# Problems getting jQuery to work in my browser (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've been following the lessons on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) and I've finished the HTML/CSS and about half of the jQuery tutorials.

I figured I should try to test my knowledge by writing code and opening it in my web browser, which is Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.131 m).

I have the HTML and CSS working perfectly fine, but I can't seem to get the jQuery (script.js is the filename) code to work properly.  Here is my code for all three files in my test project:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

*stylesheet.css*

```
div
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

*script.js*

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
   $('div').hide();    
});
```

This code basically should instantly hide a div box I am creating.  However, whenever I open the index.html page in chrome, it just shows the box in the upper left corner (thus, my `$('div').hide();` isn't being run.

My files are all in the same location:
[image]

I'm writing my code in the Sublime Text 2 IDE.

I've seen multiple questions similar to this on SO but everyone's problem was that they have didn't wrap their js code in the $(document).ready() function.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library which you have to download and include before your code. Check www.jquery.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not loaded jQuery.

Add this line to your `<head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: If you are using this offline, you need to use `http://` as it will default to `file://`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hosted by google. [Source](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Comment: Apply palm to forehead as required.

Comment: @DavidHoude Isn't working.  When I open index.html the page loads indefinitely.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix the problem. It is related to you loading the page locally.

Comment: @DavidHoude Nailed it!  I know almost nothing about web stuff so I hope you aren't secretly laughing at me ;)

Comment: Just as long as you are not laughing at me for picking the low hanging fruit for these sweet sweet internet points.

Comment: @xcdemon05 -- no, no, we aren't *secretly* laughing at you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

try to include the jquery file before your final script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
...your script....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery **before** you include your javascript file, like so:

```
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach a jquery library with your page in order to run it.

just add

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

in head section of your html

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jquery library in your html file like this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```